# How are strings on text file overwritten in Windows C programming?

Tags: c, windows, file-handling

My "*file.txt*" looks like this:

```
1 |My name is Yugal Bishram Don
2 |
```

Here **1** and **2** mean line numbers and not really exist in the file.
It means the file contains : `My name is Yugal Bishram Don\n`.
Now I open this file at `"r+"` mode and read the file rewind the pointer and write content as:

```
    FILE *fp=fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]",buffer1);
    //i did something with buffer1
    rewind(fp);
    fprintf(fp,"My name is Aswin Don\n");
    fclose(fp);
```

Now My "**file.txt**" looks like this:

```
1 |My name is Aswin Don
2 |am Don
3 |
```

But I am confused.
"**My name is Aswin Don\n**" is of *21* characters which should be overwritten on first *21* characters of the content of file i.e "**My name is Yugal Bish**" and rest of the characters i.e "**ram Don\n**" should be as it is. But it is not written as it is. "**ram Don\n**" has become "**am Don**". So my question is where the first character '*r*' of "**ram Don\n**" vanished.

Comment: Are you on Windows, where `\n` is translated to `\r\n`?

Comment: @user2357112, I am on windows 11 but I dunno what is translated to what. How can I know that?

Comment: Windows uses an awkward end-of-line convention in its files, whereby a newline is represented as two character, a "carriage return" and a "line feed".  So when you write a `\n` character in text mode, you're actually writing two characters.  Note that if you write to the file in binary mode, this substitution won't be done, but then you won't have a normal Windows text file.

Comment: How others characters are written? or this is only the special case. And where can i study abt this? Moreover when I write `\n` char manually in file, is it the same? What I mean it is again translated to `\r\n`?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the standard library uses `\r\n` combination for [end of line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Thus, when you write your sting, `\r` character is added automatically. This explains the observed one character shift. On Linux/Unix you would get a different result.

Here is a graphical representation. Ignore the `_` padding as if it wasn't there, I added these for alignment:

```
(org) My name is Yugal Bish_r_am Don\r\n
(new) My name is Aswin Don\r\nam Don\r\n
```

You can check the exact contents of the file before & after by using some hex editor, for example [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). Or using a text editor that has an option to show `CR`/`LF` characters like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/). Many text editor for programmers options like "Show all characters" or "Show line endings".

Comment: I got this but how can I get friendly with the padding  you did ? as **Bish_r_am** ,those underscores. Can I visualize them ? What is the procedure?

Comment: @MildredGallagher The underscores are merely to visually align the text, since CR/LF take one byte but we write them as two in text (\n)

Answer (score 0):

Same code i ran it overwrites as

```
My name is Aswin Don  
ram Don
```

Till `My name is Yugal Bis` it will replace `My name is Aswin Don` 20 letters.
And when \n it will replace the `h` and puts a newline the `ram is Don` will be in new line.

Comment: is it the same system as mine?